# duplicate key is still inserting as an entry in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

It just keeps adding a `row` even if it already exists and i don't get why?

```
$submitted = explode("@", $submit['tag']);
foreach ($submitted as $tag => $value) {
    if ($value != "") {
        $attag = "@".$value;
        $sql_insert = dbquery("INSERT INTO dbtags(tag_name, tag_txt) VALUES('$value', '$attag') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag_name=tag_name");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: is 'tag_name' a Primary Key? (or Unique?)

Comment: I highly recommend moving the query outside of the loop.

Comment: @Johan, its unique. Would it work better if i changed it to primary?

Comment: @Dave Chen, if i do that it wont check/insert for each of the explosions.

Comment: Unique should suffice, can you `DESCRIBE dbtags`?

Comment: @Dave Chen, its just 3 fields, tag_id, tag_name and tag_txt. tag_id is primary, tag_name is unique.

Comment: I take it your MySQL version is >= 4.1.0? :)

Comment: Try placing `values()` around the tag like this: `INSERT INTO dbtags(tag_name, tag_txt) VALUES('$value', '$attag') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag_name = values(tag_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you mean `UPDATE tag_name=tag_name` and not `UPDATE tag_name=$value` ?

Also, [use](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

It should be Unique other wise duplicate will not work . On DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag_name=tag_name")  change to On DUPLICATE KEY  IGNORE

Comment: That gave me this.. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE tag_name=tag_name'

Answer (score 0):

change tag_name data type to Binary, you may be facing problem of case-sensitiveness